# Label in HTML form will not center

Tags: html, css, forms

I have a form on a page that includes a label and a select element.

```html
<form class="w3-container" style="margin: 0; position: absolute; top: 50%; left: 50%; transform: translate(-50%, -50%);" action="" method="GET">
  <label for="instruments" class="w3-text-theme">Select an instrument</label>
  <br>
  <hr class="w3-theme">
  <select style="width: 100%;" id="instrumentList" name="instrumentList">
    <option value="null" disabled selected></option>
    <optgroup label="Horns">
      <option value="trombone">Trombone</option>
      <option value="trumpet">Trumpet</option>
      <option value="tuba">Tuba</option>
    <optgroup label="Percussion">
      <option value="bass drum">Bass Drum</option>
      <option value="drumset">Drumset</option>
      <option value="drumset4pc">Drumset 4 piece</option>
      <option value="snare">Snare</option>
      <optgroup label="Strings">
    <option value="bass guitar">Bass Guitar</option>
      <option value="guitar">Guitar</option>
      <option value="harp">Harp</option>
      <option value="violin">Violin</option>
    <optgroup label="Woodwind">
      <option value="clarinet">Clarinet</option>
      <option value="flute">Flute</option>
      <option value="saxophone">Saxophone</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

The problem is that the label for the form will not center. The form itself has been centered in the page. The label itself I cannot get centered within the form. I have tried changing it to a block element like I have read on here. I've tried margin:0; and margin:auto; and both. I have tried text-align:center; it doesn't work either. What am I missing and why can't I get the label to be centered within the form? Thanks.

Comment: If I run your provided code snippet here, then it is cenetr like you wanted. What exactly is wrong with it?

Comment: hello can you put the result af the page please ?

Comment: The "Select an instrument" text is not centered above the <hr>. It appears this way on the desktop, although you can see slightly that there is more room on the right than the left. The issue is when it comes to being responsive on mobile devices the text stays on the left, and doubles up onto two lines. I want one line of text centered above the <hr>. How would I put the results of the page? Do you mean a screenshot?

Answer (score -1):

Hey the reason `display:block` and `margin:auto` isn't working is that `block` sets width to 100%, there for leaving no space for margin to be set. You can either set width, but this is not a good way. You can instead do the combination of following properties for label.

```
display: block;
text-align: center;
```

Also you can give `text-align: center` to the form element itself if it suits your case, downside is everything will be center aligned.

Comment: run the code he provided and you'll see that everything is already centered. his issue lies somewhere else in a code he hasnt provided. He centeres everything with transform and absolute positioning.

Comment: @tacoshy I have run the code and you are right. But I assume the only case should be that he has set a width for either 'form' or 'div', so center aligning the label will make sense only then.
So what I did was set width for `form` and then checked his issue. and suggested the answer based on that.

Comment: so by only setting width, all the problems and scenarios he mentioned sets fit. You can check as well. Peace.

Comment: @tacoshy Is using transform with absolute positioning not the proper way to align the form element? When I apply the `display:block;` and `text-align:center;` it does center the text but it also pushes the text up and away from the <hr> I would like to keep it as close to the <hr> as possible. Even though centered it still drops the text to the next line. Is that because the width is not wide enough @arslanshahab? Is there a better way to align the form and the text that I am missing?